# Probability that $a^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{10}$ when $a$ is chosen randomly from a set

Tags: probability

> Out of the set $\{1,2,...,n\}$ we choose randomly a number $a$. Find the probability $p_n$ that $a^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{10}$, and find $\lim_{n \to \infty} {p_n}$

Ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All squares mod $10$ end with a $0,1,4,5,6,9$.  We know that the only numbers that when squared end with a $1$ are numbers that end in $1$ and $9$.  So this question is basically asking for "What is the probability that a number in a given set ends with a $1$ or a $9$?"

Comment: I don't get it.
Why is it that All squares mod $10$ end with a $1,4,5,6,9$?

Comment: Look at the squares of $1,...,10$ and see on what number they end. Going on with $11$ et cetera you see a repetition of this.  The mentioned limit will be $0.2$ because $2$ of the $10$ end up with $1$ or $9$.

Comment: I fixed my error.  I forgot $0$.  But anyway, if we just check the first 10 numbers, we can see what their residues mod $10$ are.  From there, you just have to realize that the number in the one's place after squaring is solely based on the number in the one's place of $a$.